# Not a valid resource name of assembly

Tags: xamarin, gtk#

I'm using Xamarin Studio and GTK#(.NET). I have the following problem:
I've made an app, and I need to(dinamically) download web images(favicons) and display them in a Gtk.Image widget. When I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'myfile.ico' is not a valid resource name of assembly 'myApp, Version=1.0.6742.24722, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
at at Gdk.PixbufLoader.InitFromAssemblyResource(Assembly assembly, String resource)
at at Gdk.PixbufLoader..ctor(Assembly assembly, String resource)
at at Gdk.Pixbuf..ctor(Assembly assembly, String resource)
at at Gdk.Pixbuf.LoadFromResource(String resource)
```

It works if i add the favicon, after download,in the resource folder, BUT I need to make this dinamically(if I add a new site, I want to see it's icon there..).
The code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
   client.DownloadFile(new Uri("https://google.com/favicon.ico", 
              Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\..\..\Res\google.ico");
}

faviconImage.Pixbuf = Gdk.Pixbuf.LoadFromResource("myApp.Res.myfile.ico");
```

The image is in the folder(i can see it, it's everything ok) but i cannot use it if i don't include it(manually) in the resource folder....

Please help me :'(

Comment: Which platform?  Generally mobile apps are sandboxed so that you can't write to files or folders within the app bundle at runtime.  You can write to user storage, and load the images from there.

Comment: Desktop(cross platform).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pixbuf.LoadFromResource` only loads image data from an embedded assembly resource. You can not add resources to assemblies after they are created.

To create a `Pixbuf` from a file, use one the its `.ator` that supports either a file path to the image or one that uses a file stream.

Something like:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "myDownloadIcon.ico");
var newPixBuf = new PixBuf(filePath):
faviconImage.Pixbuf = newPixBuf;
```

Comment: Omg! I feel so stupid lol, It was that simple... :D:D Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @FlaviusTopan 64x64 is the max. in the standards for `ico` format. From there, there are about a dozen different favicon image names that a site can use and typically those are also in the root of the site (like the favicon), than most sites support `link rel` in the `head` section of each page that specifies what the "favicon" should be for the device/browser you are currently using, so a chrome desktop browser might get a diff. favicon then Android Chrome.

Comment: I've deleted previous comment, because I thought it would be nice if I would post another question. Thanks for your answer anyway. Right now I try something like that. Thanks man! :)

Comment: @FlaviusTopan This is so when "pinning" a site to the desktop, launcher, taskbar, etc... you get the correct one. Google/Chrome supports up to 512x512 icons, Apple does up 180x180(?), etc... You would need to parse the html page fetched via different user-agent strings to determine what the site supports and if they have a different size available...  And it is not just `.ico` files being served, but png, jpg, gif, svg, browserconfig.xml, etc.... favicon is a science in and of itself and a major pain (even for the developers of browsers...)

Comment: I'll try to parse html pages to see what I'll get. Thanks! :)